# Copy Azure Infrastructure to another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, automation, cloud, virtual-machine

I have the following issue, is there any way I can copy MS Azure Infrastructure from one account to another account or subscription? By Infrastructure I mean  VMs, Storage, users, LB, CDN, Databases, etc.

Same as the original account without any changes, is there any way to make it easy? I don't want to create everything manually which will take time and effort it's huge environment. Any suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using  shared image gallery, export template from azure needs a lot of cleanup same as Rob mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to use Azure Resource Manager templates (ARM templates). ARM templates are a JSON scripting of your Azure resources. You can go to your Azure Resource Group(s) in the Azure Portal and choose "Export Templates" under settings.

In my experience, the generated templates are a bit ugly and require some cleanup. Also, some references to dependent services may be hardcoded, and those are a bit of a pain to change. Your mileage may vary if you don't have any or many dependencies.

Comment: thank you, there are another issue which is the Resource group having more than 200 resource which gives me an error every time i am trying to export it